# How to go to another page by clicking on a row of a html-table?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, model-view-controller

I have a MVC-application.

I want to go to the DetailInfo page by clicking on the row of the Index page.

How do you do that?

Part of Index.cshtml

```
        @for (var item = 0; item < Model.Count; item++)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr @@click="detailInfo(@Model[item].Id)">
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model[item].Message)</td>
```

logmessages.js

```
    const app = Vue.createApp({
         // data, functions
        methods: {
            rowClick(item) {
                console.log('Dit is regel: ' + item)
            },
            detailInfo(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<% = Url.Action("DetailInfo", "Home") %>',
                    data: { id = id },
                    succes: function (data) {
                        console.log(id + "is posted.");
                    }
                })
            },
        }
    })

app.mount('#app')
```

... and in the HomeController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DetailInfo(int id)
    {
        var dto = _logboekService.GetLogBerichtById(id);

        var model = _mapper.Map<LogBerichtDto, LogBerichtModel>(dto);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To go to another page, you could use `router.push({ path: 'home' })` as stated in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort).

Comment: Like this:                  detailInfo(id) {
            router.push({ path: 'home', name: 'detailInfo' params: { id: id } }) 
}, ?

Comment: I don't know, it depends of how your components are organized. One thing, is that you either call `name` for the component's name or `path` for some hard-coded string like (`"/admin"`). As for the params, yep you could path them like this. So, the final query may look like `router.push({ name: 'detailInfo' params: { id } })` yes.

Comment: Home(Controller), DetailInfo is the action and id is the parameter in the action.

Comment: Here, we're talking about VueJS components so there is no controller/nor any action. It's, the path you want to move to and few params that may be required **in the component**.

Comment: "/Home/DetailInfo?id=1" this is the url.

Comment: Why do you say this to me ? Your question was about `How to go to another page`, this is not useful in our context of `router.push`.